# C# offline OTP for service authentication

Tags: c#, security, authentication, one-time-password

I'm searching for a way of authentication like that from Blizzard (Authenticator). It creates an off-line OTP.
I know that larger companies use it as "tokens" however, I'm still unable to find a proper library.

So, what I want;
A project that is able to create OTPs on the client side without having the client to connect to the internet and yet be able to generate the exact same on the servers-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can take a look at this library: https://code.google.com/p/otpnet/

It is a C# port of a popular TOTP/HOTP for PHP. There seems to be a few outstanding issues in the library which have not yet been fixed by the developers but you can easily patch it on your side with recommendations that have already been submitted.

Comment: It indeed creates an OTP, however, this OTP requires a network connection. I'm searching for a connectionless client OTP generator which produces the same output on the server, or a method to use it in authentication.

Comment: I fail to see where this library requires a network connection. It never references any of .NET's networking namespaces. Besides, OTP by definition does not require any network communication what-so-ever.

Comment: Wow, I'm really sorry. I expected the project to be replaced to GitHub, here only PHP-scripts were.

Anyway, what would be the best way to make a value +/-30 second available? Getting the UNIX UTC time does one thing but second differences could be an issue, right?

Comment: Yes it could be an issue, this is why clock synchronization is important for OTP to work and is also why we usually use phones for this which are automatically sync to a time server when generating keys. Also, the TOTP algorithm I provided you will automatically take a time interval into account if provided to the constructor.

Also, just as an FYI, the dev did fix the issues I mentioned in the latest check-in so this is one less thing to worry about.

Comment: I see... Well then! Up to the drawing table. Thanks for the info.